# Sql Server - Hacer group by agrupando por grupos que se repiten en el tiempo

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, group-by, orderby

Tengo esta tabla

```
mail           group    DATE
pepemail        A    12/2/2021
pepemail        A    13/2/2021
pepemail        A    14/2/2021
pepemail        A    15/2/2021
pepemail        B    16/2/2021
pepemail        B    17/2/2021
pepemail        B    18/2/2021
pepemail        C    19/2/2021
pepemail        C    20/2/2021
pepemail        C    21/2/2021
pepemail        B    22/2/2021
pepemail        B    23/2/2021
pepemail        B    24/2/2021
```

y quiero obtener la siguiente tabla

```
MAIL          GROUP    from            to
pepemail        A    12/2/2021    15/2/2021
pepemail        B    16/2/2021    18/2/2021
pepemail        C    19/2/2021    21/2/2021
pepemail        B    22/2/2021    NULL
```

lo había hecho con una subquery con min de fecha, agrupando por mail y grupo, y después afuera usando LEAD, pero no me sirve en los casos en que estuvo en un grupo (B), después paso a otro grupo (C), y después volvió al grupo original (B)

Answer (score 0):

```
 insert into tablaTemporal(mail, grupo, Fecha) values
('papemail', 'A', '2023-05-17'),
('papemail', 'A', '2023-05-16'),
('papemail', 'A', '2023-05-15'),
('papemail', 'A', '2023-05-13'),
('papemail', 'B', '2023-05-17'),
('papemail', 'B', '2023-05-14'),
('papemail', 'B', '2023-05-11'),
('papemail', 'B', '2023-05-10')


 SELECT 
 a.mail , 
 a.grupo, 
(select MIN(Fecha) from tablaTemporal where grupo = a.grupo) as 
'From', 
(select MAX(Fecha) from tablaTemporal where grupo = a.grupo) as 
'To' 
from tablaTemporal as a 
group by a.grupo
```

Yo hice esto, creo que es lo que quieres.

Comment: Hola RPH, agradezco la ayuda, pero no es lo que necesito, ahi estas obteniendo el min y max de fechas en el que estuvo en cada grupo, y yo necesito saber durante que fechas estuvo en cada grupo, cada registro tiene correlatividad con el anterior, tengo q reconstruir un historico con un formato de scd2

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscas es un problema común con muchas soluciones. Algunas más complicadas que otras y con distintos grados de eficiencia. Una que me gusta usar es generar grupos usando un contador general para los datos y restarle un contador por grupo. Así puedes encontrar los saltos entre grupos y tendrás una columna adicional por la cual puedes agrupar.

```
CREATE TABLE #mails(
    mail     varchar(20),
    grupo    char(1),
    fecha    date
);
INSERT INTO #mails
VALUES  ( 'pepemail', 'A', '20210212'),
        ( 'pepemail', 'A', '20210213'),
        ( 'pepemail', 'A', '20210214'),
        ( 'pepemail', 'A', '20210215'),
        ( 'pepemail', 'B', '20210216'),
        ( 'pepemail', 'B', '20210217'),
        ( 'pepemail', 'B', '20210218'),
        ( 'pepemail', 'C', '20210219'),
        ( 'pepemail', 'C', '20210220'),
        ( 'pepemail', 'C', '20210221'),
        ( 'pepemail', 'B', '20210222'),
        ( 'pepemail', 'B', '20210223'),
        ( 'pepemail', 'B', '20210224');

SELECT *,   
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY mail ORDER BY fecha) -
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY mail, grupo ORDER BY fecha) grupofechas
FROM #mails;
```

Con esa columna calculada, puedes utilizar `MAX` y `MIN` directamente.

```
WITH cteMails AS(
    SELECT *,   
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY mail ORDER BY fecha) -
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY mail, grupo ORDER BY fecha) grupofechas
    FROM #mails
)
SELECT mail,
        grupo,
        MIN( fecha) AS [From],
        NULLIF( MAX( fecha), (SELECT MAX(fecha) FROM #mails)) AS [To]
FROM cteMails
GROUP BY mail, grupo, grupofechas
ORDER BY [From];
```

Finalmente, la cereza en el pastel es usar la función `NULLIF` para eliminar la fecha máxima y dejar el último rango abierto.